# winrar command line: create multiple winrar passworded files from one directory

Tags: batch-file, passwords, winrar

I want to automate compressing multiple files in a single directory, each with the same password, from the command line or with an app.

file1 -> file1(w/password).rar

file2 -> file2(w/password).rar

file3 -> file2(w/password).rar

The answer in [Packing (WinRAR) with a password on a group of files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12796665/packing-winrar-with-a-password-on-a-group-of-files) is close to what I want, but way too complicated for my needs.

I know the reverse can be done easily from the command line.

Any thoughts?  Thanks.

Comment: Please note that https://stackoverflow.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a batch code for this simple task with an extra bonus:
The working directory can be passed to the batch file as first parameter.
The current directory is used if the batch file is started with no parameter.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "WorkingDirectory="
if "%~1" == "" goto ArchiveFiles

set "WorkingDirectory=%~1"
if "%WorkingDirectory:~-1%" == "\" (
    if exist "%WorkingDirectory%*"  pushd "%WorkingDirectory%" & goto ArchiveFiles
) else (
    if exist "%WorkingDirectory%\*" pushd "%WorkingDirectory%" & goto ArchiveFiles
)
echo Directory "%WorkingDirectory%" does not exist.
endlocal
goto :EOF

:ArchiveFiles
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir /A-D /B * 2^>nul') do (
    if /I not "%%~xI" == ".rar" (
        "%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\Rar.exe" a -@ -cfg- -ep1 -idq -m5 -ma4 "-pPassword" -r- -s- -y -- "%%~nI.rar" "%%~fI"
    )
)
if not "%WorkingDirectory%" == "" popd
endlocal
```

This batch file ignores *.rar files already existing in the directory.

Open in program files folder of *WinRAR* the text file **Rar.txt** for details on used command `a` and the used switches.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?` ... explains `%~1`
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `popd /?`
- `pushd /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Read also the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) explaining `2>nul` whereby in this code the redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` to be first interpreted as literal character on parsing **FOR** command line and as redirection operator on execution of **DIR** by **FOR**.

And read also the answer on [Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564) to understand the meaning of operator `&` as used here on two command lines.